# Angular 4 reactive form - FormArray Within FormArray unable to get path

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, formarray

For a few days now Ive been trying to create a form which will alow a user to create a product, and at the same time variations of the product which may have a different price to the parent product. eg Large widget is £10, Small Widget is £5.  What I end up with every time is a FormArray within a FormArray, in other word I have a product with an array of variations, those variations have a price, but also have an array of attributes as well.  The problem comes when I try to add the controls, I can get the variation price to show up just fine, but I can't get the path in order to add the variations.attributes controls, I just get an error about ngFor only working with arrays not [Object, Object] or control is null... I've had more errors than I can remember! anyway onto my code, which has been re-written alot, and is probably worse than it started out!

first the form in my oninit:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.getAttributes(); // Get Attribute Categories      
    this.form = this.fb.group({
        name: [''],
        price: [''],
        description: [''],
        stockRef: [''],
        attributes: this.fb.array([{
            attributeCategoryId: [''],
            name: [''],
        }]),
        variations: this.fb.array([{
            vprice: this.vprice,
            vattributes: this.vattributes
        }]),
    });
}
```

The section for adding and removing attributes for the Master Product, which works fine:

```
addAttribute(id: any, name: any) {
    if (!id.value || !name.value)
        return;
    this.attributes = <FormArray>this.form.get('attributes');
    var newAttribute = this.fb.group({
        attributeCategoryId: [id.value],
        name: [name.value],
    });
    this.newlist.push({ name: [name.value].toString(), attributeCategoryId: [id.value].toString() });
    this.attributes.push(newAttribute);

    id.value = '';
    name.value = '';
}
removeAttr(i: any) {
    this.attributes.removeAt(i);
    this.list2 = [];
    this.newlist.splice(i, 1);
}
```

The part where I add variations, which works, it still has the code which I used to try and copy the attributes added to the main product, into the variation, which worked I think, but just couldn't get access to the values in order to display them, variations.attributes didn't work for the path.

```
initVariation() {
    let v = this.fb.group({
        price: [''],
        vattributes: this.attributes //COPIES main attributes            
    });
    this.attributes.reset(); //Reset the main attributes as they now      
    return v;                //belong to a variation 
}
addNewVar() {
    const control = <FormArray>this.form.controls['variations'];
    control.push(this.initVariation());

}
```

The part that adds attributes to the variation, which does not work, and is where I'm having issues in my component.ts

```
addAttrRow() {
    const control = <FormArray>this.form.controls['variations.vattributes']
    control.push(this.initVattr())
}
initVattr() {
    let va = this.fb.group({
        vattributeCategoryId: [''],
        vname: ['']
    })
    return va;
}
```

Finally, my html which is even more of a mess lol:

```
<h1>New Product</h1>
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="save()">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Product Name</label>
                <div *ngIf="!form.get('name').valid" class="alert alert-danger">
                    {{ form.get('name').getError('remote') }}
                </div>
                <input [(ngModel)]="name" type="text" formControlName="name" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Price</label>
                <div *ngIf="!form.get('price').valid" class="alert alert-danger">
                    {{ form.get('price').getError('remote') }}
                </div>
                <input [(ngModel)]="price" type="number" formControlName="price" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Product Description</label>
                <div *ngIf="!form.get('description').valid" class="alert alert-danger">
                    {{ form.get('description').getError('remote') }}
                </div>
                <textarea formControlName="description" class="form-control"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
            <div>
                <h4>Attributes</h4>
                <div class="form-inline" >
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div formArrayName="attributes">
                            <select #ac name="attributeCategoryId">
                                <option value="" selected>Category</option>
                                <option *ngFor="let a of attriblist;let i = index" value="{{a.id}}">{{a.name}}</option>
                            </select>
                            <input #a name="name" placeholder="Attribute name" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="addAttribute(ac,a)">Add Attribute</button>
                </div>
                <br>
                <table class="table-bordered table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Attr. Category</th>
                            <th>Attr.</th>
                            <th><button type="button" (click)="addNewVar()" class="btn btn-primary">Add Variation</button></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr *ngFor="let a of form.value.attributes; let i = index;"  >
                            <td *ngIf="i > 0">{{a.attributeCategoryId}}</td>
                            <td *ngIf="i > 0">{{a.name}}</td>
                            <td *ngIf="i > 0"><button (click)="removeAttr(i)" class="btn btn-danger">X</button></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--Variations Start-->
    <div class="row" formArrayName="variations">
        <div *ngFor="let variation of form.controls.variations.controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
            <h5>Variation #{{ i + 1 }}</h5>
            <p></p>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Variation Price</label>
                <input name="vprice" style="max-width:50px" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Attr. Category</th>
                        <th>Attr.</th>
                        <th><button class="btn btn-success" (click)="addAttrRow()">+</button></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody name="vattributes">
                    <tr *ngFor="let attribute of variation.get('vattributes'); let ii = index;">
                        <td><input type="text" name="vattributeCateforyId" /></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="vname" /></td>
                        <td><button (click)="removeVAttr(ii)" class="btn btn-danger">X</button></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="removeVariation(i)">Delete</button>

        </div>
        </div>
    <!--Variations End-->
    <br>
    <p>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
    </p>
</form>
```

Comment: I have doubt about how your attributes and variations should be linked but we can start with this https://plnkr.co/edit/9FcYTmz15t7hkVlTtBdD?p=preview I remove attributes list after user adds new variation with these attributes

Comment: @yurzui Ahh so don't add the controls / arrays in the declaration, and when adding the attribute rows to the variation use "const control = <FormArray>this.form.get(['variations', index, 'vattributes']);" (I missed the index from the path) Now I understand the error when I was getting cant find control with variations > 0 > vattributes! Thank you.  If you can make this an answer I will mark it accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see a lot of mistakes in your code.

For example

1) you should be aware that we need not to forget about index when deal with getting control from `FormArray`

So instead of

```typescript
const control = <FormArray>this.form.controls['variations.vattributes'];
```

we should use

```typescript
addAttrRow(index) {
  const control = <FormArray>this.form.get(['variations', index, 'vattributes']);
```

2) If you don't specify type for `button` it will have `submit` as default value.

```typescript
<button class="btn btn-success" (click)="addAttrRow()">+</button>
```

and it can lead to unpredictable situations.

So try to specify `type="button"`

3) You iterate over object

```typescript
*ngFor="let attribute of variation.get('vattributes');
```

while you need to iterate over array

```typescript
*ngFor="let variation of form.controls.variations.controls;
```

I created **[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/9FcYTmz15t7hkVlTtBdD?p=preview)** that can help you to realize what you did wrong